# Morse code translator Loop the same sentence

Tags: led

I'm a newbie so forgive my ignorance.

I'am using the Morse code translator to light up the LED which is fine but after it has processed the sentence it turns off. How can I get it to loop the sentence continuously.

Thanks

Comment: Add the code and we will be able to tell you something

Comment: -1 until some code arrives

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the [sketch](http://www.instructables.com/id/Morse-Code-Translator/step5/Program/) you are using. It reads characters from Serial and translates them to Morse code.

What you need to do to make it loop a sentence is, 1) read a sentence into a buffer, 2) loop though the buffer and translate to Morse code.